# What controls the native/default file chooser that applications use in linux?

Tags: linux, file-management

So in any application I use that has a "Choose a File" (or similar) dialog, it's always the same one (excluding small java apps that use Swing's builtin File Manager and similar situations). It's been a year or two since I've dealt with "file choosers" but it was with Java, and I just remember being able to set the look and feel to "Native" or whatever and it would use Windows' native file chooser.

In Linux, which application provides the file chooser to applications? I always that it was the default file manager but that doesn't seem to be the case as far as I can tell. I'm using Thunar as my file manager in XFCE but the shortcuts I have in my side pane in Thunar don't match those that are in the shortcuts side pane of the file chooser which is what leads me to believe another application/library provides the file chooser functionality.

**What I mean:**

My shortcuts in the file chooser (I deleted most of them to show that they aren't the same ones kept in Thunar):

[image]

My shortcuts in Thunar:

[image]

So...

<del>What software provides the file chooser for applications?</del> **The widget toolkit (GTK, Qt, etc.) (Thanks Ignacio!)**

<del>Is it the graphical toolkit that the applicatoin is using (GTK, Qt, etc.) that provides it, perhaps?</del> **Yes**

**If so, how can I make it use my Thunar shortcuts if at all possible?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is in fact the widget toolkit that provides the file selection dialog. <s>Having said that, I don't see a real difference in the selection of locations between the two, only the ordering.</s>

EDIT:

I don't know of any automatic way to share bookmarks between the two, but the GTK+ bookmarks are stored in `~/.gtk-bookmarks`; it may be possible to use something like incron to watch the Thunar/Gigolo bookmarks and duplicate them in the toolkit settings.

Comment: That's what I expected, thanks. The difference is my customized favorites/shortcuts that show up in Thunar under places and in the GTK file manager under the device/partition list. I'll edit the question with new images.

Comment: Hrm. I figured the solution would be hackish. Thanks, although I just (re)discovered nemo and I'm just going to use that isntead of Thunar now. My bookmarks are fairly important to me, I'm lazy :P